# $x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)<x-\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}, x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, rolles-theorem

Show that-
$$x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\ln(1+x)<x-\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}, x>0$$

I can prove this by observing that at $x=0$, the three functions in the above inequality (say $f_1<f_2<f_3$) are zero. And for $x>0$, the derivative of the difference of $f'_2-f'_1>0$ and $f'_3-f'_2>0$ therefore the inequality is satisfied.

I am looking for an elegant solution to this using some kind of Mean Value Theorem maybe, if possible.

Comment: Although this is a repeat question, the solution provided here is more interesting than that in original question. If this question is going to be deleted, is there any way below solution can be transported to that question? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for any $x>0$ we have $\log(1+x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t}$, where $\frac{1}{1+t}>1-t$ is trivial and
$$ \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t} = x-\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{t+1}\,dt<x-\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{x+1}\,dt = x-\frac{x^2}{2(x+1)}. $$

Comment: It appears the question is a duplicate.